# How to restrict a logon to a specified Ip Address Range using B2C Custom Policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, identity-experience-framework

I use a B2C Custom policy to sign in users. Is it possible to restrict the users so they can only signin from a specified Ip Address (or range)?

Comment: Hi Douglas, Do you have any working solution for this? I have tried below solution provided by Chris and it is working to a certain extant but not restricting the access to users who's IP address is not matched. Is it possible for you to share your experiance with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also create a claims transformation that checks whether a client IP is trusted or not as follows.

1. Create one claim type, such as **clientIP**, of type **string** that represents the client's IP:

```xml
<ClaimType Id="clientIP">
  <DisplayName>Client IP Address</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

And another claim type, such as **isTrustedIP**, of type **boolean** that represents whether a client IP is a trusted IP or not.

```xml
<ClaimType Id="isTrustedIP">
  <DisplayName>Is Trusted IP Address</DisplayName>
  <DataType>boolean</DataType>
</ClaimType>
```

2. Create a claims transformation, such as **SetIsTrustedIPClaim**, of type [**SetClaimsIfRegexMatch**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/string-transformations#setclaimsifregexmatch) that checks whether the client IP matches a trusted IP (e.g. "216.3.128.12" or [any regular expression for an IP address or range](https://www.analyticsmarket.com/freetools/ipregex/)) or not and, as result, sets the **isTrustedIP** claim to `true` or `false`:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="SetIsTrustedIPClaim" TransformationMethod="SetClaimsIfRegexMatch">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="clientIP" TransformationClaimType="claimToMatch" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="matchTo" DataType="string" Value="^216\.3\.128\.12$" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isTrustedIP" TransformationClaimType="regexCompareResultClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

3. Create [a technical profile for the claims transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claims-transformation-technical-profile) so that the claims transformation can be invoked from an orchestration step:

```xml
<ClaimsProvider>
  <DisplayName>Claims Transformation</DisplayName>
  <TechnicalProfiles>
    <TechnicalProfile Id="ClaimsTransformation-SetIsTrustedIPClaim">
      <DisplayName>Set Is Trusted IP Claims Transformation</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
      <Metadata>
        <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
      </Metadata>
      <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="clientIP" DefaultValue="{Context:IPAddress}" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isTrustedIP" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <OutputClaimsTransformations>
        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="SetIsTrustedIPClaim" />
      </OutputClaimsTransformations>
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </TechnicalProfiles>
</ClaimsProvider>
```

4. Invoke the claims transformation technical profile from the orchestration step:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="ClaimsTransformation-SetIsTrustedIPClaim" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ClaimsTransformation-SetIsTrustedIPClaim" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

The following orchestration steps can then allow or deny access based on whether the **isTrustedIP** claim is set to `true` or `false`.

You can create a selfAsserted page that acts as a block page:

```xml
<TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-BlockUser">
    <DisplayName>Block page</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
    <Metadata>
        <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.showContinueButton">false</Item>
        <Item Key="setting.showCancelButton">false</Item>
    </Metadata>
    <InputClaimsTransformations>
        <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateError"/>
    </InputClaimsTransformations>
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserMessageDenied"/>
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserMessageDenied" Required="true"/>
    </OutputClaims>
    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
</TechnicalProfile>
```

Create an error message to display

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateError" TransformationMethod="CreateStringClaim">
    <InputParameters>
        <InputParameter Id="value" DataType="string" Value="Your IP is blocked." />
    </InputParameters>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="UserMessageDenied" TransformationClaimType="createdClaim" />
    </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Then call it from the userJourney to evaluate `isTrustedIP`, which then calls the block page:

```xml
<OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <Preconditions>
        <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
            <Value>isTrustedIP</Value>
            <Value>True</Value>
            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
        </Precondition>
    </Preconditions>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="BlockUser" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Selfasserted-Blockuser" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: Hi Chris, Quick question, After adding the final step (OrchestrationStep) to SignUpOrSignIn user journey as order 1 do we still have to follow any additional steps? Currently, the above solution is still giving access to application even if the IP is not trusted.

Comment: @jas-suri-msft,Thank you for updating the answer. By using above solution user is been restricted or shown with error page after login. Is it possible to check the client IP and show error page on click of a SignIn button? We have tried validating technical profiles of "ClaimsTransformation-SetIsTrustedIPClaim" and "SelfAsserted-BlockUser" under self asserted-social and SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email and it didn't work.

Comment: Hi @Chris Padgett, can we leverage this to call API endpoint and check if IP is allowed to login or not. Something stored in DB for users and verify that on users login?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no such feature in Azure AD B2C. You can submit a feedback on [Microsoft Azure Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).

You can try to implement this by yourself, kindly refer to the idea below.

You can call a REST API and pass it the IP address. The IP address can be resolved using a Claims Resolver. If it’s one IP address then you can do a claim transform in the policy to check if the user ip matches. Otherwise if it needs to check the user ip in an ip range, then you need to do that logic in a REST API.

Similar approach to this:

https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/relying-party-rbac
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/claim-resolver-overview

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but there has been a new feature called conditional access. More details can be found in the documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/conditional-access-technical-profile